# Extending a data frame with a column, only using positive numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to calculate the average of a column in an external file which I loaded into a data frame. I only want to calculate the average of positive numbers in the Column "DEPARTURE DELAY". To do so I thought of extending the data frame with a column only using the positive numbers and all negative ones should be replaced with a 0. Is that possible? If not are there other ways?

[image: This is my data frame]

Comment: `df.loc[df['DEPARTURE_DELAY'] > 0, 'DEPARTURE_DELAY'].mean()` would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
 {
 "CARRIER": ['9E', '9E','9E', '9E', '9E'],
 "ORIGIN": ['ATL','ATL','ATL','ATL','ATL'],
 "DESTINATION": ['CSG', 'CSG','CSG','CSG','CSG'],
 "DEPARTURE_DELAY": [-2, -5, -5, -5, -5],
 "PLANNED_DURATION": [47,47,47, 47, 47],
 "ACTUAL_DURATION": [37, 32, 39, 37, 41],
 "DISTANCE": [83, 83, 83, 83, 83]
 }   

)
```

As you asked for replacing all values less than 0 to 0, you can do it using

```
num = df._get_numeric_data() # since you have columns that are not numeric
```

OR

```
num = df.select_dtypes("number")
```

num[num<0] = 0 # replace all negatives with 0

```
To get mean: `df.mean(numeric_only=True)`
```

Comment: Since it starts with `_` and lacks a documentation, I'd say `df.select_dtypes("number")` is preferred over `df._get_numeric_data()`.